# How to filter on an optional table produced by a left join in slick

Tags: scala, slick

I need to apply a filter on an attribute of an optional table produced by a left join in scala `slick`. I could not find any documentation on this or any similar questions online.

Consider the following query:

```
val query = FirstTable joinLeft SecondTable on (_.foreignId === _.id)
```

I would like to filter is by an attribute of the `SecondTable`:

```
query.filter {
  case (firstTable, secondTableOpt) => secondTableOpt.attribute === "value"
}
```

Obviously this does not compile since `secondTableOpt` is a `Rep[Option[SecondTable]]`. There does not seem to be a `.get` method on the `Rep` object.

There should be a way to write this in `slick`, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you filter `SecondTable` before the join?

Comment: Well, because I simply did not think of filtering before! This is probably it, thank you very much!

Comment: I will put it as an answer to explain it a bit better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you need to filter the results in your `SecondTable` in the result, it is better if you do it before the left join. So the code will be something like this:

```
val filteredSecondTable = SecondTable.filter(_.attribute === "value")

val query = FirstTable joinLeft filteredSecondTable on (_.foreignId === _.id)
```