# How to unwrap Rep object of Slick in Scala?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am using [Slick](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/queries.html) for first time, as an FRM tool with **Scala** and **MySQL**.

However while writing query with multiple joins, I realised that I can't access some intermediate objects further to filter based on it.

i.e. **rep1** here, which is of type **Rep[Option[Manufacturer]]]**

How can I unwrap this object to **Manufacturer** so that I can access columns of it ?

```
val query = product
      .joinLeft(manufacturer).on { case (prod, man) => prod.manufacturerid == man.manufacturerid }
      .joinLeft(category).on { case ((prod, rep1), cat) => prod.categoryid == cat.categoryid }
    // .filter() after this using rep1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter on an optional table produced by a left join in slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864185/how-to-filter-on-an-optional-table-produced-by-a-left-join-in-slick) Another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572566/slick-3-1-left-joins-and-filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Pratik Shah and welcome to Stackoverflow.

I find it useful to think of anything inside a `Rep` as running in the database (as part of SQL). With that in mind, you don't unwrap a `Rep`: you use it within a Slick query (and the result of running the query with kind of unwrap in a sense to a plain value).

So if you can access `rep1` inside the `filter`, you can use Slick's operators (e.g., `===` not `==`, note) to use the `Option[Manufacturer]` value as part of a query. I can't say for sure without running the code but it'll perhaps be something like:

```
filter { case ((prod, rep1), cat) => rep1.map(_.manufacturerid) === 42 }
```

... or whatever you want to do with `rep1`